# How to delete bash history in python script on Mac?

Tags: python, macos, bash, history, delete-file

I want to delete bash history with a python script on my Macbook Pro.

I know two ways to delete bash history with bash shell

1.rm ~/.bash_history

2.history -c

But these command does not work in python script with subprocess:

1.rm ~/.bash_history

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call([‘rm’, ‘~/.bash_history'])
```

error:

rm: ~/.bash_history: No such file or directory

2.history -c

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['history', '-c'])
```

error:

> File "test.py", line 8, in 
>      subprocess.call(['history', '-c'])
>   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line >524, in call
>      return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
>    File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line >711, in **init**
>      errread, errwrite)
>    File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line >1308, in _execute_child
>      raise child_exception

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two questions here:

First, python doesn't understand `~`, you need to expand it:

```
subprocess.call(['rm', os.path.expanduser('~/.bash_history')])
```

Second, `history` is a shell built-in.  Use the shell to invoke it:

```
subprocess.call(['bash', '-c', 'history -c'])
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply.
I have tried the code.
'subprocess.call(['rm', os.path.expanduser('~/.bash_history')])'
works great!
    subprocess.call(['bash', '-c', 'history -c'])

Comment: But subprocess.call(['bash', '-c', 'history -c']) did not work....

I tried to edit the comment to a good format, but the system told me "comment can only be edit in 5 minutes". It's the first time I edit the comment, I am sorry for making it hard to read. @devnull

Comment: @Matt `history -c` does __not__ delete `$HOME/.bash_history`.  It simply clears the history list in the current session.  From the terminal try saying: `history -c` and then `cat ~/.bash_history` and you should be able to figure.  You could also try `history -w` followed by `history -c`.

Comment: @Matt In short, removing the file is the option that you might want to consider.  Moreover, if you don't want `bash` to log `history` in a file, you can include the line `export HISTFILE=/dev/null` in your `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: And subprocess.call(['rm', os.path.expanduser('~/.bash_history')]) can delete the file. But when I run "history" in the shell, I can still see the command history. I am sorry to say the problem is still unresolved.

Comment: @Matt I see.  This __wouldn't__ work from python the way you're expecting.  There is __no way__ that you can do anything in python to make the shell history vanish, i.e. saying `history` after exiting python, and not produce any output.  The simple reason is that you are not executing `history -c` and `history -w` in the __same__ shell environment.

Comment: I get it. Maybe disable bash history is the option I should try. Thanks! @devnull